# Why do only about 20% of the people with a heart attack report a near-death experience?

Tags: neuroscience

It has been shown that only around 20% of people who get a [cardiac arrest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_arrest) and revived could tell something about a near death experience (NDE). But if an NDE is considered to be something with the brain, why don't more people get an NDE?

[Parnia, S; Spearpoint, K; Fenwick, PB (August 2007). "Near death experiences, cognitive function and psychological outcomes of surviving cardiac arrest.". Resuscitation. 74 (2): 215–21. PMID 17416449. doi:10.1016/j.resuscitation.2007.01.020](https://m.horizonresearch.org/Uploads/parnspearfenwresuc.pdf).

Comment: Have you done research on NDEs themselves? From a conscious awareness point of view, I believe there is variability depending on the individual. I can't answer this because I am not a psychology or health care professional, but I recall some discussion where certain people are more likely to experience NDEs than others (people with significant OCD were an example).

Comment: The paper you cited says no conclusive studies existed to date on the mechanisms of NDE, but that there are many theories... and has about half a page summarizing them.